# Codeigniter create library function switch case

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I make a library with switch case function in Codeigniter, but it's didn't work with error

So, it's my view

```
<?php foreach ($project as $row) {
    $this->category->get_category($row->icon);
    echo $job;
    echo $icon;
    $this->category->get_category($row->name);
}
?>
```

And, it's my library function

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

 class Category {
    public $job;
    public $icon;

     public function get_category($data){
        switch ($data) {
            case 'w':

            $this->job = 'Web Development';
            $this->icon = 'code';
            break;
        case 'd':
            $this->job = 'Design';
            $this->icon = 'paint brush';
            break;
        case 'p':
            $this->job = 'Photography & Videography';
            $this->icon = 'camera retro';
            break;
        case 'm':
            $this->job = 'Mobile App';
            $this->icon = 'android';
            break;
    }
    $job = $this->job;
    echo $job;
    return $job;
}
 }
```

And my controller

```
...
public function project(){
        $data['project']=$this->site_model->project_select();
        $this->category->get_category('w');
        $this->load->view('media/head');
        $this->load->view('media/project',$data);
        $this->load->view('media/foot');
    }
...
```

Are my code it's wrong? Please Help..

Comment: you have to call that in controller. not view

Comment: are you getting any specific errors??

Comment: yes, the error is undefinded variable

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$job

Comment: what code should I write to call it from controller? sorry, i'm new with codeigniter

Comment: you declare public `$job` and `$icon`

Comment: @JonathanTyar this should `$this->category->get_category('w');`call in controller

Comment: @Abdulla still didn't work

Comment: @bvp it's still same show error

Comment: @Abdulla are it's possible to call the function from view? cause I get 'w' it's from foreach

Comment: Have you got a class on your library I do not see it there

Comment: `<?php foreach ($project as $row) {
 $this->category->get_category($row->icon);
 echo $job;
 echo $icon;
 $this->category->get_category($row->name);
}
?>`

Comment: you can call model function in view but this is not how MVC is designed to function in simple way put queries in model call model in controller and pass data from controller to view and echo data in view

Comment: @anmolraghuvanshi can you give me a tutor or a code?

Comment: @JonathanTyar http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Framework-Basic-Tutorial-P841.html this will good place to start

Comment: maybe dont echo before return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

library:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Category
{
    public $job;
    public $icon;

    public function get_category($data)
    {
        switch ($data) {
            case 'w':
            $this->job = 'Web Development';
            $this->icon = 'code';
            break;
            case 'd':
            $this->job = 'Design';
            $this->icon = 'paint brush';
            break;
            case 'p':
            $this->job = 'Photography & Videography';
            $this->icon = 'camera retro';
            break;
            case 'm':
            $this->job = 'Mobile App';
            $this->icon = 'android';
            break;
            default:
            $this->job = 'No found';
            $this->icon = 'no found';
        }
        return array('job'=>$this->job,'icon'=>$this->icon);
    }
}
```

controller:

```
...
public function project()
{
    $data['project']=$this->site_model->project_select();

    $this->load->library('category'); //load library
    $data['lib_category'] = $this->category; //add library function to view

    $this->load->view('media/head');
    $this->load->view('media/project',$data);
    $this->load->view('media/foot');
}
...
```

and view (media/project):

```
<?php foreach ($project as $row) {
    //what is $data for get_category($data) ?? - i use: $row->icon (w or d or p or m)
    echo $this->lib_category->get_category($row->icon)['job'];
    echo $this->lib_category->get_category($row->icon)['icon'];
}
?>
```

it should work! :)

Comment: forget about it, I forget to write echo XD Thanks for your help